# xsl fo internal link does mot work across different page sequences

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I got multiple page sequences which is necessary cause the data displayed has different parameters (some landscapes and some portrait). I struggle to build a ToC with links:

```
<fo:page-sequence id="toc">
<fo:page-sequence id="data1">
<fo:page-sequence id="data2">

<xsl:template name="toc">
  <fo:flow>
   <fo:block>
        <fo:basic-link internal-destination="data1">
          data 1
          <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
          <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="data1"/>
        </fo:basic-link>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:flow>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the following warning:

```
1 link target could not be fully resolved and now point to the top of the page or is dysfunctional
```

So the internal-destination cannot resolve the ID it always links to the start of the document but I want it to link to the top of the first page of the data1 page sequence.

If I put an ID that is nowhere in the document for internal-destination the link is fully broken and I get an error as expected. The page number shown for the data1 sequence is correct. Is it not possible to just link to a certain page? This would circumvent the problem.

I have to use XSL 2.0 and Xalan.

Update: 
Now the problem gets really weird. I got a footer in a "region-after" like this:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
  <fo:block>
    <fo:inline>
      <fo:page-number/>
      /
      <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="data5"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

`data5` beeing the last page sequence. If I put in `data4` the link to `data5` works but not to the others. If I take it out completely all links work! So this `<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="data5"/>` to get the last page number to put it into the footer is actually the problem. Why is that? How else do I get the last page number?

Calling page-number-citation-last thing in the footer seems to block the links!

Comment: Is the correct page number generated?

Comment: Yes it is I just updated the question with new information that makes the behavior even more unexpected to me...

Comment: It looks to me like a bug in FOP.  Are you using the most up-to-date version?

Comment: I just updated it to the most recent version. Same behavior. Is there a way to circumvent this and somehow get the total page count in another way?

Comment: You could do it the old-fashioned way and add an empty `fo:block` with a known ID as the last thing in the last `fo:page-sequence`.

Comment: Good suggestion but unfortunately: Same effect with either ```page-number-citation``` or ```page-number-citation-last```. Calling that inside the footer template kills the links. Calling it anywhere else does actually not. If I call it only in the footer of a specific page-sequence then only the link to that sequence does not work. So that means all that call one of these in either header or footer cannot be linked to currently. Thats totally weird...

Comment: I tried with a variable now: ```<xsl:variable name="pagecount">
        <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="end"/>
      </xsl:variable>``` - but that variable is empty when I try to get its value. I could pass this as parameter if I get the variable filled.

Comment: Page numbers won't be known until the document is formatted.  It seems that your question about `fo:basic-link` has morphed into a question about `fo:page-number-citation-last`.  Should you start a new question about that?

Comment: Well its kinda ... both. But I guess its really a bug in fop cause the behavior should not be this way. I will try to build a minimal (non) working example and fill a report.

Comment: The problem is likely using an id on the page-sequence. This does not work in some cases mostly because of the way formatter content is internalized.  page-sequence does not really create any content in the output, it controls the page information. If you want links to point to the start of the page-sequence, use something in the flow that is at the start or create you own. Put a block inside the page-sequence with id and all content inside or throw an empty one at the start.

Comment: If you wish to try with the placing id on something at the overall level, trying moving those id references down to fo:flow inside the page-sequence, that tends to works better.

Comment: @KevinBrown seems like you are actually right. I made a minimum template to test out this issue and it works if all ids are strapped to the very first block in the body flow. Strapping the ID to the flow itself did not help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the ID of the element that generates the first area inside the `fo:page-sequence`.  If that doesn't have an ID, then give it one using `generate-id()` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-generate-id).